# How to split a table with many columns into two pieces?

Tags: tables

I have a table with 16 columns and it gets very hard to read on an A4 page.
What I want is to split this table into two tables, both having half of the columns,
and put them one over the other, the first aligned to the left and the second aligned to the right.

This is the code of my table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{A sample of the Smartphones Database} % title of Table
    \label{tab:smartphonesDB}
    \centering % used for centering table
    \gdef\rownumber{}
    
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            %\rowcolor{LightGray}
            \textbf{Make} & \textbf{Model} & \thead{\textbf{CPU}\\\textbf{Make}} &
            \thead{\textbf{CPU}\\\textbf{Model}} &
            \textbf{GPU} &
            \textbf{Storage} &
            \thead{\textbf{Removable}\\\textbf{Storage}} &
            \textbf{RAM} & \textbf{OS} & \textbf{Height} &
            \textbf{Width} & \textbf{Depth} & \textbf{Weight} & \thead{\textbf{Display}\\\textbf{Size}} &
            \thead{\textbf{Dispaly}\\\textbf{Type}} &
            \thead{\textbf{Camera}\\\textbf{Resolution}}\\
            \hline          
            Google & \shortstack{Pixel\\4} & Qualcomm & \shortstack{Snapdragon\\855} & \shortstack{Adreno\\640} & 128 & 0   & 6 & \shortstack{Android\\10}  & 147.1 & 68.8 & 8.2 & 162 & 5.7 & OLED & 12\\
            \hline
            Google& \shortstack{Pixel\\4 XL} & Qualcomm &   \shortstack{Snapdragon\\855} &  \shortstack{Adreno\\640}    & 128   & 0 &   6   & \shortstack{Android\\10} &    160.4 & 75.1 &  8.2 &   193 & 6.3 & OLED &  12\\
            \hline
            OnePlus & 7 &   Qualcomm &  \shortstack{Snapdragon\\855} &  \shortstack{Adreno\\640} &  256 & 0 & 8 & \shortstack{Android\\9.0 Pie} &   157.7 & 74.8 & 8.2 & 182 & 6.4 & AMOLED & 48\\
            \hline
            OnePlus & 7 Pro&    Qualcomm&\shortstack{Snapdragon\\855}&\shortstack{Adreno\\640}  &256&   0   &12&\shortstack{Android\\ 9.0 Pie}& 162.6&  75.9&   8.8&    206&    6.7&    AMOLED& 48\\
            \hline
            Asus & \shortstack{ZenFone\\6} & Qualcomm&\shortstack{Snapdragon\\855}& \shortstack{Adreno\\640}&   256&    1024&   8   &\shortstack{Android\\9.0 Pie}& 159.1&  75.4&   9.2&    190&    6.4&    IPS LCD&    48\\
            \hline
            Vivo&   iQOO&   Qualcomm&\shortstack{Snapdragon\\855}&  \shortstack{Adreno\\640}&   256&    0   &12&\shortstack{Android\\9.0 Pie}&  157.7&  75.2&   8.5&    196 &6.4    &AMOLED &12\\
            \hline
            Vivo&\shortstack{iQOO\\Neo 855}&    Qualcomm&\shortstack{Snapdragon\\855}   &\shortstack{Adreno\\640}&  256&    0&  8&\shortstack{Android\\9.0 Pie} &159.5& 75.2&   8.1&    199 &6.4&   AMOLED& 12\\
            \hline
            Nokia&\shortstack{9\\PureView}& Qualcomm&\shortstack{Snapdragon\\845}&\shortstack{Adreno\\630}& 128 &512&   6&  \shortstack{Android\\9.0 Pie}&  155.0&  75.0&   8.0 &172&   6.0&    P-OLED& 12\\
            \hline
            Sharp&\shortstack{Aquos\\Zero}& Qualcomm&\shortstack{Snapdragon\\845}&\shortstack{Adreno\\630}& 128 &0  &6& \shortstack{Android\\9.0 Pie}&  154.0&  73.0&   8.8&    146 &6.2&   OLED&   22\\
            \hline
            Vivo&\shortstack{iQOO\\Neo}&    Qualcomm&\shortstack{Snapdragon\\845}&\shortstack{Adreno\\630}& 128 &0& 8&  \shortstack{Android\\ 9.0 Pie}& 159.5&  75.2&   8.1 &199&   6.4&    AMOLED& 12\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

and it gets displayed as

[image]

How can I create something like below?

```
[Table with first 8 columns]
[Table with first 8 columns]
[Table with first 8 columns]
[Table with first 8 columns]
                 [Table with next 8 columns]
                 [Table with next 8 columns]
                 [Table with next 8 columns]
                 [Table with next 8 columns]
```

Comment: Is the question about how to have two tabulars below each other, one flush left and one flush right, or how to reformat the already existing table automatically without having to split it manually?

Comment: something like the answer below

Comment: Before splitting your table see, if having table in landscape orientation is an acceptable option.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the table horizontal

Comment: Yes, two tabular with flush would be enough. I can do it manually

Comment: Depending on the size of the textblock, you might even be able to fit the whole table onto a landscape page. (Do you really need the "CPU Make"  column? All entries seem to be identical...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, makecell}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{A sample of the Smartphones Database} % title of Table
        \label{tab:smartphonesDB}
        \centering % used for centering table
        \gdef\rownumber{}
\noindent\hspace{-3cm}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                %\rowcolor{LightGray}
                \textbf{Make} 
                    & \textbf{Model} 
                        & \thead{\textbf{CPU}\\\textbf{Make}} 
                            &\thead{\textbf{CPU}\\\textbf{Model}} 
                                &\textbf{GPU} 
                                    &\textbf{Storage} 
                                        &\thead{\textbf{Removable}\\\textbf{Storage}} 
                                            &\textbf{RAM} \\
                \hline          
            \end{tabular}


\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{OS} 
        & \textbf{Height} 
            &\textbf{Width} 
                & \textbf{Depth} 
                    & \textbf{Weight} 
                        & \thead{\textbf{Display}\\\textbf{Size}} 
                            &\thead{\textbf{Dispaly}\\\textbf{Type}} 
                                &\thead{\textbf{Camera}\\\textbf{Resolution}}\\
    \hline          
    
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**edit -- to show connecting arrow**

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{A sample of the Smartphones Database} % title of Table
        \label{tab:smartphonesDB}
        \centering % used for centering table
        \gdef\rownumber{}
        \noindent\hspace{-3cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            %\rowcolor{LightGray}
            \textbf{Make} 
            & \textbf{Model} 
            & \thead{\textbf{CPU}\\\textbf{Make}} 
            &\thead{\textbf{CPU}\\\textbf{Model}} 
            &\textbf{GPU} 
            &\textbf{Storage} 
            &\thead{\textbf{Removable}\\\textbf{Storage}} 
            &\textbf{\tikznode{PT}RAM} \\
            \hline          
        \end{tabular}
        
        
        \vspace{1cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{\tikznode{PB0}OS} 
            & \textbf{Height} 
            &\textbf{Width} 
            & \textbf{Depth} 
            & \textbf{Weight} 
            & \thead{\textbf{Display}\\\textbf{Size}} 
            &\thead{\textbf{Dispaly}\\\textbf{Type}} 
            &\thead{\textbf{Camera}\\\textbf{Resolution}}\\
            \hline          
            
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,cyan,rounded corners,>=stealth,shorten > =1pt,shorten <=1pt,thick]
        \draw[->] (PT)++(1,0)--+(1,0)--+(0,-1) -| (PB0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to also make a line connecting the two header rows, so that it is clear it's a single table?

Comment: @1Z10  -- please see the edit above